# how to run loop for float value in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I make a simple demo of `apply template` in xslt .
http://xsltransform.net/bwdwsv/2

I added condition so that it run recursively .

```
   <xsl:apply-templates select="//col[position()&lt;= 3]/sec" mode="list"/>
```

**Cases**
when I pass value `1` it show `2` value

```
   <xsl:apply-templates select="//col[position()&lt;= 1]/sec" mode="list"/>
```

**output**

```
 <div class="news-list1">
      <div class="a">a1</div>
      <div class="a">a2</div>
   </div>
```

when I pass `2` value it show `4` value

```
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//col[position()&lt;= 2]/sec" mode="list"/>
```

**output**

```
   <div class="news-list1">
      <div class="a">a1</div>
      <div class="a">a2</div>
      <div class="a">b1</div>
      <div class="a">b2</div>
   </div>
```

can I pass `2.5` value ???.I want `5` value ..MEAN 
**Expected output**

```
   <div class="news-list1">
      <div class="a">a1</div>
      <div class="a">a2</div>
      <div class="a">b1</div>
      <div class="a">b2</div>
      <div class="a">c1</div>
   </div>
```

I tried like this

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="//col[position()&lt;= 2.5]/sec" mode="list"/>
```

but it not work ?
any way to achieve this

Comment: If you want to limit the number of  `sec` elements why can't you simply use `<xsl:apply-templates select="(//sec)[position() &lt;= 5]"/>`? Currently you limit the number of `col` elements processed and of course `position()` is always an integer so a comparison of `<= 2` or `<= 2.5` does not make a difference.

Comment: see http://xsltransform.net/bwdwsv/3 ..it is not expected output

Comment: Well, I left out the mode so in the context of your complete code you can use `<xsl:apply-templates select="(//sec)[position() &lt;= 5]" mode="list"/>`.

Comment: yes ..I got it ..!! but is there any other way to achieve the same result